# Control content type availability based on day and time

Tags: forms, rules, webforms, datetime

I have a website that delivers products that are ordered during the day.  I would like the order form to only be available during business hours.  Outside of those hours, the form shouldn't be available for ordering.

I am using [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) but I can easily enough create my own content type if needed.  I've looked into using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but I am not sure how to write the rules to accomplish this.

I thought there would already be a quick and easy module for this, but I have not been able to find one.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straight forward with rules.

1. Create a page called "Order Form Unavailable" with your message about products only being available during the day.
2. Enable the PHP Filter module.
3. Create a rule with event "Content is viewed" of type "Order form Webform" (Or whatever)
4. Add condition "Execute custom PHP code".

Add the following into the PHP text area...

```
if( (date('H') < 9) && (date('H') > 17) ){
 // before 9AM and after 5PM
 return TRUE;
}
```

5. Add action "Page Redirect" to redirect the user to the "Order Form Unavailable" page.

Comment: Thanks Collins, this works beautifully, but I changed the && to || as it was always evaluating as false.  If you could, I would like to refine the statement to include days of the week and minutes also.  My hours are:
Sunday 11am-4:45pm
Monday-Sat 9am-8:45pm

I tried this but I can't get the minutes to work:
if( (date('w') == 0) && (date('H') < 11) || (date('H') > 17) ){
 // Sunday before 11AM and after 5PM
 return TRUE;
}

Answer (score 0):

using your excellent answer and a little of my own brain power (which I don't like doing.. ;) I came up with this.  It works, but if anyone has more "elegant" code, please share it:

```
$hhmm = date('H') * 100 + date('i');
  // converts and joins hours and minutes
if( (date('w') == 0) && (($hhmm < 1100) || ($hhmm > 1645))) {
 // Sunday before 11AM and after 4:45PM
 return TRUE;
} elseif( ($hhmm < 0900) || ($hhmm > 2045) ) {
 // All other days 9AM and after 8:45PM
 return TRUE;
} else {
 return FALSE;
}
```